# Coax cable + BNC temperature response

Tags: coax

I have a couple of cheap prefabricated 1m 50 Ohm cables terminated with male BNC connectors. These connect to a device in an environmental test chamber which is cycling between 5 degC and 60 degC.

I suspect there may be problems with signal integrity - is this likely? The signals of interest are at 120kHz with a typical peak to peak value of 100mV feeding into a 10K input impedance. Nothing visible on the scope, but the changes I am looking at are timing related in the nS.

Comment: Nanoseconds or nanosiemens? I can't see how temperature cycling could significantly affect the propagation delay or characteristic impedance of the cable, but it will certainly cause a change in d.c. resistance more than a few nanoohms.

Comment: Well, forget the timing issue at present. Are all such cable assemblies rated to 60 degC? The one I am using has no temperature specs

Comment: No, not all are. Typical RG58 or RG174 cable is rated for use at -40 to +80°C, but who knows about your specific assemblies. Cables with PTFE dielectric and/or sheath are operable over a wider temperature range.

Comment: OK. I will get a couple of expensive well specified cables and see if that is the problem. The other problem might be that it could come into contact with organic vapors, so it must be PTFE.

Comment: The Keysight guys were demo- ing some equipment - a cheap <$2 50 ohm BNC coax cable measured more like 60 ohms! The $300 1m cable was much better.

Comment: If you want to  "forget the timing issue at present" then, instead of changing streams in mid-horse,  it would be better if you edited  your question  stating specifically what your problem is or what rating you're looking for.

Comment: Not really, because the problem only shows up in statistics so I cannot say exactly what causes it. It does *appear* to be connected with which cable is used and alters according to temperature but the link is not conclusive. So I was asking about cable characteristics and temperatures

Comment: If you are feeding into a 10k load with 50\$\Omega\$ cables, then it sounds like you have a signal integrity problem even before anything has shifted in the environmental oven. I would not personally use BNC cables for anything involving measurement at all, only use them for logic triggers and the like. Use a screw connectored cable, SMA, N type or TNC if you want to be happy that the connection is stable with changing temperature. On a general note, if a product is not specified for something, then you can expect to be disappointed with its performance if you try to use it.

Comment: It's not going to make much difference at 120kHz (sine wave) over 1 metre